# How to specify query in sqlite with min() function

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, select

I have table defined by code below

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
P_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT,
price REAL,
sellPrice REAL,
plu INTEGER,
codeBar TEXT,
tax INTEGER,
amount INTEGER,
date TEXT
);
```

and when I try to execute query like that I get a syntax error (it's a prepared statement)

```
select * 
from Products 
where P_Id = min(select P_Id from Products where codeBar=?);
```

Can somebody please help? What is wrong with this query?

The exact error message I get is:

> *java.sql.SQLException: near "select": syntax error*

Thx for help.

Answer (score 5):

`MIN()` should be inside the subquery.

```
select * 
from Products 
where P_Id = (select min(P_ID) from Products where codeBar=?);
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' (*around 15mins to an hour later*)  by clicking the white check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is this:

```
select * from Products 
where P_Id = (select min(P_Id) from Products where codeBar=?);
```